# Yii2 : Converting a raw query into ActiveRecord

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I have a query which goes into this way.

```
select t.id,
  t.ad_id,
  sum(t.impression) total_impression,
  sum(t.view) total_views,
  sum(t.clicks) total_clicks,
  t.publisher_id,
  i.budget,
  i.name_of_campaign
from
  (select id,
     ad_id,
     max(impression)  impression,
     max(view)  view,
     max(clicks)  clicks,
     visitor_ip,
     publisher_id
  from ad_analytics
  group by ad_id, visitor_ip) t
  inner join inventory i
             on i.id = t.ad_id
group by t.ad_id;
```

I want to convert the same for yii2. The query which I have written is.

```
//For model
use frontend\models\Inventory;
use frontend\models\Adanalytics;
```

And for grid view in the same model.

```
$ivcsubquery = Adanalytics::find()->
                  select('id,ad_id,date_event,max(cpc) cpclick,max(cpv) cpview,max(impression) impression,max(view) view,max(clicks) clicks,visitor_ip,publisher_id')->
                  from('ad_analytics')->
                  where(['publisher_id' =>  Yii::$app->user->identity->id ])->
                  groupBy('ad_id,date_event,visitor_ip');
        $ivcquery=Adanalytics::find()->
                // $subquery = select('id,ad_id,max(impression) impression,max(view) view,max(clicks) clicks,visitor_ip,publisher_id')->
                //     from('ad_analytics'),
              //where(['publisher_id' =>  Yii::$app->user->identity->id ])->
              select('t.ad_id,t.date_event,sum(t.cpclick) total_click_cost,sum(t.cpview) total_view_cost,sum(t.impression) total_impression,sum(t.view) total_views,sum(t.clicks) total_clicks,t.publisher_id')->
              from(['t'=>$ivcsubquery])->
              groupBy('t.ad_id,t.date_event');



      $query = Inventory::find()->
      where(['publisher_name' =>  Yii::$app->user->identity->id ])->
      andWhere('ending_date>= NOW()')->
      andWhere('paid=1')->
      andWhere('status=1');

      $joinquery = "Really I don't know what to write down here";
```

And in my grid view which looks like this.

```
  'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            //'id',
            'user_id',
            'placed_date',
            'name_of_campaign',
            'budget',
            //'start_date',
            //'platformType',
            'titleOfTheVideo',
            'videoUrl',
            'ending_date',
   ]
```

Also columns are called in at the above way How can i solve this issue?

Comment: you have column is select not mentioned .. in group by  .. this can create problem using most recent version of db  ..

Comment: @scaisEdge But how can i solve this?

Comment: @scaisEdge I have tried the peerbits answer and if I try a `var_dump` for peerbits answer I am getting the result but if I pass it is showing bug.

Comment: the 2 queries you wrote do they give you the desired results individually, are the results correct?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam That I don't know but the raw SQL is giving me the desired result anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the RawSql query you wrote is giving you the desired results if run on the table using phpmyadmin or any other utility you can transform it into the following.

```
$subQuery = Adanalytics::find()
        ->select([new Expression('[[id]], [[ad_id]], MAX([[impression]]) as impression, max([[view]]) as view, max([[clicks]]) as clicks,[[visitor_ip]],[[publisher_id]]')])
        ->where(['publisher_id' =>  Yii::$app->user->identity->id ])->
        ->groupBy('[[id]], [[visitor_ip]]');

$query = Adanalytics::find()
        ->select([new \yii\db\Expression('t.[[date_event]], t.[[id]], t.[[ad_id]], sum(t.[[impression]]) as total_impression, sum(t.[[view]]) 
         as total_views, sum(t.[[clicks]]) as total_clicks, t.[[publisher_id]], i.[[budget]],i.[[name_of_campaign]]')])
        ->from(['t' => $subQuery])
        ->innerJoin('{{%inventory}} i', 'i.id=t.ad_id')
        ->groupBy('t.ad_id, t.date_event');
$query->all()
```

Just make sure that the foreign keys that you use to join the other tables should be specified in the select otherwise it may give you an error like column not found / or unknown column.

Comment: I am getting this error `The "query" property must be an instance of a class that implements the QueryInterface e.g. yii\db\Query or its subclasses.`

Comment: Also, I have removed `->all();` From the query and tried to display data but I am getting the error saying `Getting unknown property: frontend\models\Adanalytics:: budget` Also for other columns as well

Comment: the budget is the inventory table field you must be referencing it incorrectly using the alias `t` rather than `i` @arunwebber

Answer (score 0):

Try this Query . This query return records as array.

```
$connection = \Yii::$app->db;
$model = $connection->createCommand('
                                  select t.id,
                                    t.ad_id,
                                    sum(t.impression) total_impression,
                                    sum(t.view) total_views,
                                    sum(t.clicks) total_clicks,
                                    t.publisher_id,
                                    i.budget,
                                    i.name_of_campaign
                                  from
                                    (select id,
                                       ad_id,
                                       max(impression)  impression,
                                       max(view)  view,
                                       max(clicks)  clicks,
                                       visitor_ip,
                                       publisher_id
                                    from ad_analytics
                                    group by ad_id, visitor_ip) t
                                    inner join inventory i
                                               on i.id = t.ad_id
                                  group by t.ad_id;
                                ');
$users = $model->queryAll();
```

Comment: but i am using grid view in this way. `'dataProvider'=>new ActiveDataProvider([
          'query' => $query,
        ]),
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,`

Comment: Than dont use last line , 'dataProvider'=>new ActiveDataProvider([ 'query' => $model, ]), 'filterModel' => $searchModel,

Comment: I am getting this error now `The "query" property must be an instance of a class that implements the QueryInterface e.g. yii\db\Query or its subclasses.`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a working SQL query you may consider using [`SqlDataProvider`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-data-sqldataprovider) instead of rewriting the whole query:

```php
$sql = <<<'SQL'
from
  (select id,
     ad_id,
     max(impression)  impression,
     max(view)  view,
     max(clicks)  clicks,
     visitor_ip,
     publisher_id
  from ad_analytics
  group by ad_id, visitor_ip) t
  inner join inventory i
             on i.id = t.ad_id
group by t.ad_id;
SQL;

$selectSql = <<<SQL
select t.id,
  t.ad_id,
  sum(t.impression) total_impression,
  sum(t.view) total_views,
  sum(t.clicks) total_clicks,
  t.publisher_id,
  i.budget,
  i.name_of_campaign
$sql
SQL;

$countSql = 'select count(*) ' . $sql;

$dataProvider = new SqlDataProvider([
    'sql' => $selectSql,
    'totalCount' => Yii::$app->db->createCommand($countSql)->queryScalar(),
    'pagination' => [
        'pageSize' => 20,
    ],
]);
```

Comment: I am getting this error `Setting unknown property: yii\data\SqlDataProvider::0`

Comment: @arunwebber Are you sure that you copied everything correctly? It looks like you omitted key name in configuration array.

Answer (score -1):

The task was one-time and sounded like "get only those orders from the old database, information about which is available in the new database."

```php
    $limit = 1000;

    if( $type = 'viaRawSQL' ) {

        $sql = <<<SQL

    SELECT * FROM db1.orders
    LEFT JOIN db2.orders ON db1.orders.order_id = db2.orders.order_id
    WHERE db2.orders.order_id IS NOT NULL
    LIMIT $limit

    SQL;

        $activeQuery = new ActiveQuery( OrderOld::class );

        $activeQuery->sql = $sql;

    }
    else if( $type == 'viaModel' ) {

        $activeQuery = OrderNew::find()
                               ->where( [
                                   'vat' => null,
                               ] )
                               ->andWhere( [
                                   'not', [ 'invoice_number' => null, ],
                               ] )
                               ->limit( $limit )
        ;
    }

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider( [
        'query' => $activeQuery,
        'sort'  => [ 'defaultOrder' => [ 'order_id' => SORT_DESC ] ],
    ] );

    // OR get all models
    $index = $activeQuery->all();
```