# Yii2 over partition to activerecord

Tags: activerecord, yii2

```
SELECT
  mksg_id,
  valid_from,
  price
FROM (SELECT
  prices.*
  , MAX(valid_from) OVER (PARTITION BY mksg_id) max_date
FROM prices) s
WHERE valid_from = max_date
```

How can I turn that to ActiveRecord? Thank you.

Comment: You need to use the Subquery which is mentioned in this  duplicate [Yii2 : Converting a raw query into ActiveRecord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50215060/yii2-converting-a-raw-query-into-activerecord)

Comment: Also you should properly use the table aliases in your query when specifying columns you are not using `s` alias for the subQuery any where in the main query, so apparently the columns will be ambiguous, you should fix your raw query first

Comment: I'm getting the following: `...) "t" WHERE "valid_from"='max_date'` note the double and the single quote? I get ORA-01858.

Comment: i can't get anything that you are saying until you add your current code you are working on. please update your question by editing it